# How do I a display a list as a table within an email body string?

Tags: python, html

I currently have a list derived from a data frame field and want to display that list as a table within a string.

I am stuck on displaying that list as a table within the body string of the email instead of outside.

My ultimate goal is to automatically create table rows from the name list instead of manually creating html script for each individual row/name. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

The list looks like:

```
names = [John Appleseed, Amy Adams, Robert Feller]
```

and want to show that as a one column table (without that blank right column):

| Names |  |
| --- | --- |
| John Appleseed |  |
| Amy Adams |  |
| Robert Feller |  |

So far, I have something like:

```
subject = 'Test'

body = """

hello, here is your email

"""

email_to = ['jackdaniels@gmail.com']


email(email_to, subject, body, email.config, attachment]
```

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by "as a table"?  Do you mean the HTML `<table>` element?  Or do you mean plain text that is arranged in rows and columns?

Comment: @JohnGordon arranged in a tabular format as a column with a row for each name

Comment: If you want plain text output, you'll have to give an example.  The example you gave was very much like an HTML table.

Comment: @JohnGordon not sure if it’s plain text output, but I’d like the bordered lines similar to an html table. I am struggling with printing such table in the string of the body however

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an HTML table created automatically:

```
from tabulate import tabulate

names = ['John Appleseed', 'Amy Adams', 'Robert Feller']
names = [[x] for x in names]

table= tabulate(names,tablefmt='html',headers=["Names"],stralign=("left",))

body = body + table
```

If you want plain text change tablefmt 'to pretty' or 'simple'

Comment: Sorry if this is already obvious but how would I print the tabulate “table” within the body of that email string?

Comment: body = body + table

Comment: Thank you, that worked for automatically adding rows. Is there a way to print the table with borders?

Comment: This link contains all the formats available https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/ , change tablefmt='html' to tablefmt='simple_grid' or look for the other formats. Can you accept the answer?